# URLs without tracking querystrings

Tags: firefox, browser, website, browser-addons, privacy

When I want to share a URL, e.g.   `https://www.example.com/legit-part-of-the-url?q=legitquerystring&ref=tracking-thing1&someid=tracking-thing-2`

Sometimes I remove the tracking things, leaving me with `https://www.example.com/legit-part-of-the-url?q=legitquerystring` for brevity (URLs without query strings are often 3-4x shorter, and this matters when sending a link in a group message) and for the reason that the URL "works" with just those components, I don't need the extra tracking things, so why use them?

Often webpages sport a "share" button which has a short sharable link, often they don't (when they want to emphasize other share options like in-platform features, or "share to facebook/twitter" buttons but no links).

For the cases where websites don't have a friendly way to share short clean links, I'm wondering what's a way to do this.

What would be the working principle of getting such clean URLs, would it have to be a crowdsourced list (like ad-blockers) or is there an easier way to achieve this?

Are there existing solutions (websites, services, addons) which do this?

Comment: This question is unanswerable as it requires getting in to the mind of the website designer. The additional parameters could be for obnoxious things like tracking or useful things like hints for navigating away to other items, to information usefilfor logging to bad programming off the top of my head.

Comment: @davidgo so much for your your un-answerability objection

Comment: @davidgo By the way, questions which have a pretty clear objective and legitimate basis but no currently feasible solutions also have a place on stackexchange. Before being posted it's in the realm of unknown unknown, after being posted it becomes a known unknown: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92890/265751

Comment: I was responding to ", I don't need the extra tracking things, so why use them?" - I did not read past that. You are possibly right. I should have voted to close the question on the grounds that software recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: @davidgo now that you've posted the actual closevote reason, I've modified the question and the answer so it no longer asks for software recommendations and is useful to a wider audience. Hope this is better.

Comment: You.might want to reread your last 2 paragraphs... This question really doesn't fit here, and I doubt it could be shoe horned to.

Comment: Also, URL shorteners like bit.ly

Answer (score 0):

When posting this question I did not know how I'd find a solution if it existed. After posting, I remembered that webpages offer [a canonical URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element) for search engines which I could extract if I wanted to build this extension on my own.

I searched for extensions with the keyword "canonical" and found a perfect extension for firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/canonical-link

This may be useful to others for finding existing extensions for their own browsers, or making their own.